# Make a link clickable in AlertDialog window in Android App

Tags: android, hyperlink, android-alertdialog, clickable

I need to open a link (only if I click on it)(for example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantico_(TV_series)) in a AlertDialog window open by onPostExecute method:

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    String res=result.replace("^", "\n");
    String link=result.substring(result.indexOf("[") + 1, result.indexOf("]"));
    res=res.replaceAll("[.*?]", "");
    res=res.replace("[", "");
    res=res.replace("]","");
    alertDialog.setMessage(res+link);
    alertDialog.show();
    //System.out.println("RESULT FOUND ===>> "+ res);
    //UtilityFunct.list.clear();
}
```

This is an example of output on my Nexus 5X:

[Output on my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKrL0.jpg)

I have used the "replace" to isolate the link that I need to make clickable. 
I have tryed many ways that I have found in stackoverflow, but no one work.

How can I do? Is it possible?
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this following code

```
TextView message = new TextView(YourClass.this);
SpannableString s = new SpannableString("Text with like http://yoursite.com"");
Linkify.addLinks(s, Linkify.WEB_URLS);
message.setText(s);
message.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
alertDialog.setView(message);
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But I cannot make it work. I have an error in "YourClass.this". I have tryed with every class of my project (String, AlertDialog, BackgroundTask...) and don't work

Comment: Did you check with only (this)?

Comment: Yes, doesn't work. Maybe the problem is to use TextView inside an AlertDialog?

Comment: What is the name of your class where you place that onPostExecute ?

Comment: The name of the class is "BackgroundTask" that we use to estabilish a communication with PHP script. The variable "String result" that is passed to onPost, derive from a PHP script that work on database. Could it be the problem?

Comment: I got it. i want to know what is the parent class of BackgroundTask?

Comment: this is the declaration of the class: 
    'public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {'

Comment: what is the name of your main activity class where you use (public class BackgroundTask). Asynctask class always be as inner class. i want to know what is the main class of this?

Comment: the main class is "MainActivity" where I call the "BackgroundTask"

Comment: use MainActivity.this

Comment: I've tryed, but doesn't work. The error is: "MainActivity not an enclosing class"

Comment: use getApplicationContext()